# What is the maximum number of real roots a polynomial of any degree can have?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is the following reasoning correct?

According to the complex conjugate root theorem, the number of complex roots of a polynomial is always equal to its degree.

Since odd degree polynomials have a maximum of 2 turning points, they can have a maximum of 3 real roots. And since even degree polynomials have a maximum of 1 turning point, they can have a maximum of 3 real roots.

Therefore, the maximum number of a real roots a polynomial of any degree can have is 3, all other roots are non-real.

Comment: $(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n)$ has $n$ distinct real roots. A polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n-1$ turning points.

Comment: http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/Math/Precalculus_obj/turningPoints.htm

Answer (score 5):

I don't know where you got the information that an odd degree polynomial has at most two turning points:

[image]

Actually the maximum number of turning points of a degree $n$ polynomial is $n-1$ and the one in the picture indeed has four of them, and five real roots.

Generalizing, if $n$ is any positive integer, the polynomial
$$
(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n)
$$
has $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: What is that nice application?

Comment: @LeeMosher Grapher, which comes along with Mac OS X

Comment: Hah, seems I overlooked that since... forever.